# Who are the shadows that speak to Grand-Fisher?

Tags: bleach

In the first season at episode 8, before Grand-Fisher leaves for the world of the living one of the rocks casts a large shadows before 4 other shadows shoot out and take form on rocks around Grand-Fisher, they apparently speak to him as he replies that he'll go and deal with Ichigo himself

I am wondering who these shadows are and if they are related to Aizen or are they a separate faction that don't support Aizen

[image: Shadows coming out of shadows cast by rocks]

[image: 3 of the 4 shadows that came out]

[image: one of them close up]

[image: another one, deafen toy a Hollow because of the hole]

EDIT: got some screenshots, there are 4 shadows but we only ever see 2 close up

Comment: Do you have any pictures of this?

Comment: @kuwaly no but i'm sure it's at the start of the episode, i'll jump on youtube tonight to see if i can find the episode there and screen shot it (since i can't access youtube at work)

Comment: @kuwaly added photos, also mistook episode, it's episode 8 not 10

Comment: The bottom picture is Ulquiorra that's all I know

Answer (score 1):

It's never specified exactly who they are other than than the fact that they're hollows but based on the fact that they appeared to be more humanoid than most hollows it's safe to assume they were Vasto Lorde (strongest form of natural hollow). They also could be some of the Espada pre-arrancar since Harribel (#3) was revield to have been a Vasto Lorde it would make sense for other high level Espada to Vasto Lorde as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Arrancar were created using Aizen's Hogyoku, a long time before the series started.  I think the two that we see there are Aisslinger Wernar and Tier Harribel.  Harribel is the one that looks like Sheik, wrapped up in bandages, though her hollow hole being on the outside of her body rather than in her womb leads me to believe that it was an initial design.